# How to save MS Word document directly to Google Docs or Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

The goal is to work in MS Word but save it in Google Docs. Somehow smoothly, right from MS Word, without copy/paste. Is it possible with Google Docs?

Comment: Do you want to _convert_ to Google Docs format, or just store the file?

Comment: @AlE. Just to store would be enough if it is not possible to store AND convert right away to GDocs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Save, edit & share Microsoft Office files - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6167634?hl=en)

> ## Save, edit & share Microsoft Office files
>
> You can use Google Drive to work with Microsoft Office files in two
>   ways:
>
> - From web browsers or with sync clients
> - Directly from your Microsoft Office programs
>
> To use a web browser or sync clients, learn more about using Google
>   Drive apps.
>
> ### Google Drive in Microsoft Office
>
> You can install the Google Drive plug-in for Microsoft Office. The plugin works with Word, Excel,
>   PowerPoint, and Outlook (2007, 2010, 2013, and 2016). You can also use
>   Office 365 if you subscribe and install it on your computer.
>
> After you install the plug-in, you'll see "Google Drive" in the Office
>   menu bar.
>
> Note: The plug-in does not work with Office for Mac.

Follow the link at the top of this answer to find out the specific instructions.

Answer (score 3):

If you install [Google Drive](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive) on your PC it basically creates a directory you can browse to like any other folder on your computer.  You can save the word document to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can flip it on it's head and work on your MS files from Google Drive with this Chrome extension from Google - [Office Editing for Docs, Sheets & Slides](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en)

From the extension description:

> View and edit Microsoft Word, Excel, and PowerPoint files with Google
>   Docs, Sheets, and Slides

Just be aware that you may have some formatting issues.